# what kind of pointcut the @Transactional aspect has? Before, After or Around?

Tags: spring, transactional, aspects

When is going to explain Spring aspects the mandatory example usually are transactions and logging )))

So the question I was recently asked is: what kind of pointcut has @Transactional aspect? Before, After or Around?
( any other clarifications are appreciated!)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of a theoretical question (interview, explanation, etc), Transactional support can be implemented as an "Around" advice in terms of AOP.

**Explanation:**

An **Around** advice provides a hook both before and after the execution of an actual code, and this is exactly what is needed for implementing `@Transactional` logic.

Before the "applicative" code gets executed, spring will open a transaction, or alternatively will implement more sophisticated logic (like nested transaction support, etc. This is called propagation; there is also isolation - all of them technically can be set up as parameters of `@Transactional` annotation)

After the applicative code gets executed, spring should check the result, and commit or rollback a transaction depending on the status (usually, if the applicative code throws an exception, the rollback should be done, if all is ok - commit.

Note, also that the terminology you've used in question "what kind of pointcut has @Transactional aspect" is not totally accurate.

*Pointcut* in AOP defines at what joinpoints the associated Advice should be applied.

All the logic that handles transaction can be implemented in an *Advice* of type *around*.

Comment: I wonder that how It commit at the end of execution? For example, If method A call method B, method B call method C. How It know that It should not commit after retuning of method B and C, and just commit after returning of method A?

Comment: Advice is just a code invoked in appropriate place. if you put `@Transactional` annotation on method A it will do whatever you need "before" this method and after this method. Its up to you to decide what exactly should be done (commit in this case).

Comment: What happend if all of methods A,B,C annotated with @Transactional (Or they are in a class that annotated with @Transactional)? Does commit happen when returning of each method A, B, C?